# MongoDB indexes size in Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm Basically using a Replica Set with 3+ instances running.

My index size is currently :

```
"indexSizes" : {
    "filename_1" : 63290416
}
```

I have read that it has to fit in the RAM to avoid [The Foursquare Crash](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/10/15/troubles-with-sharding-what-can-we-learn-from-the-foursquare.html), but as I have 3+ servers, should they all have 64Go ( which is REALLY expensive :'( ) ? If it's a yes then I probably have to review my indexes ...

Big Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexSizes` returns indexes in Byte, which makes only 63M ... should be alright !